# Can someone tell me where to connect the white, black and ground wires from my new light fixture to these existing wires.

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light

[image]. This is what I'm looking at  I'm just lost as what to connect to what

Comment: I Hope you are planning on putting in a junction box in, so it will help protect the connections, once identified

Comment: Are you trying to tap constant power, or a switched hot?

Comment: Have you already removed the old light fixture from this wiring.....or are you adding a new light in a different location?    Looks like 2 3 way switches are involved.   The red wire is most likely the traveler between the two switches.  Do you have an Voltage Tester?

Comment: I appreciate the picture - but I see one white disconnected, one white is wire nutted to a black wire (code violation and wrong). I see 2 reds together. I also see what looks like a second fire hazard over to the middle right . I would like a wire drawing of what is actually there - if you could do that. Bundle 1 : Red to Bundle 2 red . Also as others have commented PLEASE .. buy a junction box it will set you back a whopping $4  but will make sure that is code worthy and safe - which is why it is code.

Comment: It is not a code violation to have a black nutted to a white. A white wire can be used for a line hot or a switched hot. It should be marked with a black marker or a piece of black tape, but I don't think that leaving that off is a code violation.

Comment: How many lights are controlled by the two switches?  Is this one of several light locations, or the *only* light location?

Comment: Note to world: These types of situations would be soo much better if we knew what was there before and how it was connected.

Answer (score 2):

First, we do not do splicing in open space like this.  All these cables need to terminate in a proper junction box, with cable clamps attaching the cable to the junction box, clamping the undamaged full cable, not individual wires.  If you can't find a junction box big enough, get two or more steel junction boxes and an EMT nipple or short length of EMT conduit with adapters to connect them.   One of these boxes can be the lamp junction box itself.  The lamp must also attach to a junction box embedded in the ceiling.

Here's what I see.  I could be wrong.

There are three Romex cables running through the area, but with no connections.  They have nothing to do with it and can be forgotten about.

The top and left cables go to 3-way switches.   Any system of 3-way switches has **two** wires which are **travelers**.  The travelers are interchangeable.  The travelers can be any colors, but in *these two* cables, they are red and black in both cables.  I would run, not walk, to the nearest home improvement store and get a 5-pack of colored electrical tape, and mark all 4 of those wires with yellow tape, to designate them as travelers.  You won't be dealing with them again.

The ground wires are ground wires. They all go together and done.

From here we have two possibilities.

### Single lamp, power provided here.

In this scenario the right cable is the power supply.

The flopping around loose white wire from the left cable is actually switched-hot. My preference is to mark switched-hot wires with red tape.  This goes to the lamp hot wire (black or brown).

The flopping around white wire coming from the right cable is the actual neutral.  Lamp neutral (white or light blue) goes there.

### Dual lamps, power from leftside switch.

In this scenario the right cable goes to another lamp controlled with this one.

There should be a bundle of actual neutral wires.  Thing is, all the wires in this bundle will be white.  You see 2 loose white wires, and of course the white from the lamp itself.  Those had been a bundle, but were disassembled. They all go together in the neutral bundle.

Now the only wires we haven't accounted for are the white from the top cable and the black from the right cable.  I assume that bundle is *switched-hot* and the right cable heads off to another light.  I prefer to mark these with red tape.  Attach your lamp's hot wire to this bundle.

Comment: Don't forget to remind him to get all those splices stuffed into a box attached to the joist below :)

Comment: With Proper wire clamps to hold the romex  and prevent damage!